Karate-Gatling: JSON Feeder value is getting converted into Scala Map Object
My Scenario: I have a JSON file with array of JSONs
Example:
[
  {
    "url": "https://springboot.app.com/abcd",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {},
    "status": 200
  },
  {
  "url": "https://springboot.app.com/healthcheck",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
    "body": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    "status": 200
  }
]

I am reading this JSON file in scala and then calling a .feature file to execute the API Test.
In my API test I want to specify URL, header, body, etc from the values of the JSON file.
The Problem: The issue is for Key like 'headers' and 'body' (which have nested JSON), the Scala is converting them into Map or HashMap type of object.
Now, I cannot use them in .feature file like this:
  Scenario: Api Test
    Given url __gatling.url
    And request __gatling.body
    When method __gatling.method
    Then assert responseStatus == __gatling.status

Can someone please help me.
In short, I have some details in a JSON file realted to API and want to use them to run a API performance test.

this is beyond the scope of karate, so I think you have to figure this out on your own
